# Calculate sum of a dynamically generated columns in Jquery datatable

Tags: jquery, datatable, datatables

I have a Jquery datatable which is dynamically populated from a JSON data. I need to calculate the sum of numbers in certain column and create a new column dynamically to show the sum. I am new to Jquery datatables and I am not sure if this is possible and If possible,how it needs to be done.

My datatable and jquery code to populate it is :

```
$.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "/project/resourceData/",
                    dataType: "json", 

                    success: function(result) {
                        $('#resourceData').show();
                        var data=result;
                        if ($.fn.DataTable.isDataTable("#resourceData")) {
                              $('#resourceData').DataTable().clear().destroy();
                              $('#resourceData').empty();
                            }
                        $('#resourceData').dataTable({
                            data:data.data,
                            columns:data.columns,
                            });
```

My current data table is displayed like this :
[image: My Current Datatable]

In this both the column headings and data are dynamically generated. Here P12W3 means Period 12 and Week 3.
I need to add a new Columns to after each period data to have the sum of the numbers in that period for all weeks.
Example, I need to add P12W3 + P13W2 and create a new columns as P12 to show the sum in each row.

My Expected Datatable should be something like this :

[image: Expected Data table]

Can someone please help me to understand, if this is possible and how it can be done. Any help on this will be appreciated. Thanks in Advance!!

Comment: you can set the data for the sum column to null data: null and then use the render: function( data, type, row, meta ){}  The row object contains the properties for all column in the row.  you can use that to access other columns and add them and return the result in the function which will populate the column.  https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.render

Comment: alternatively, you can do this sum on the server side and expose the sum properties in json and bind to them on the column data

Comment: @PaulZepernick, yes - exactly what OP should do.